# ggplot in r - date on x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I want to ask about the `ggplot2`
[Datasets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoMzq.png)

Date is classified as the "date format". However, when I tried to draw timeseries from `ggplot` it shows strange x axis.

```
ggplot()+ 
    geom_line(data = Farm.MLR, aes(x = date, y = observed), colour = "black")+ 
    scale_x_date(labels = function(x) format(x, "%d-%b-%y"))+ 
    geom_point(data = Farm.MLR, aes(x = date, y = observed), colour = "black")+ 
    xlab("Date") + ylab("SM")
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyuF6.png)

Do you have any idea what's problem with my code?

Comment: Note that a picture of the dataset is not useful.

Comment: @ed_sans what kind of additional information is useful?

Comment: the data.frame using e.g. dput(). See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @J.con Same results even editing...

Comment: structure(list(date = structure(c(13551, 13560, 13615, 13631, 
13800, 13807, 13816, 13823, 13832, 13919, 13928, 13960, 13992, 
379241, 14008, 14063, 14072, 14095, 14104, 14184, 14191, 14207
), class = "Date")

Comment: @ed_sans Thank you I think '379241' seems problem.. even i read data from the excel..

Answer (score 3):

Formatting function is not correct, should be

```
 scale_x_date(date_labels= "%d-%b-%y"))
```

instead of

```
scale_x_date(labels = function(x) format(x, "%d-%b-%y"))
```

Comment: And use date_breaks to control the distance between axis breaks (e.g., scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d-%b-%y", date_breaks = "1 month").